# How to echo alert todays date using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

```
echo '<script>alert('.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').')</script>';
```

I am a beginner and I would like to ask how is it possible for me to alert the current datetime. I tried the above code but it is not working.

Comment: you can't mix the javascript code with php

Comment: <script> alert(new Date()) ; </script>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I take it your date is a php var so you are breaking out of the single quote for the echo, but if it is a string, your js needs to be surrounded in quotes.

Try this:

```
echo '<script>alert("'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'")</script>';
```

Note the double quotes that will be echoed out around the date string

Answer (score 1):

Use script tag to enclose the alert as follows

```
echo '<script>alert("'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'");</script>';
```

Comment: That will produce invalid JS.

Comment: We can echo this in a php document and get a alert with date and time

Comment: It won't work. Have a look at @amateur's answer to see why.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(new Date())
```

will be all that's required

In case you want to format it as well, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Will that display the date in the format the OP wants?

Comment: The question was merely about the date. OP didn't specify the format. Have added an addendum if that is indeed what he wants.

Comment: The OP's existing code as shown in the question specified a particular format.